Does richly endowed mean wealthy?
Wikipedia says

In the account of Dares the Phrygian, Achilles was described having "... a large chest, a fine mouth, and powerfully formed arms and legs. His head was covered with long wavy chestnut-colored hair. Though mild in manner, he was very fierce in battle. His face showed the joy of a man richly endowed."

Does richly endowed mean wealthy? What does the joy of a man richly endowed look like?

Ask Dares the Phrygian. This is a question about ancient Greek literature and hence doesn't belong on English Language Learning.

@StuartF Well arguably, the passage is an English translation; we're not actually talking about the Greek language. Meanwhile Tim, all the surrounding context is about physical appearance and ability. Although "endowed" can have financial meanings, it seems perverse to reach for a meaning that has nothing to do with the context. Please use the "Edit" button to show that you've looked up the word "endowed"; when I do so, I find "provide with a quality, ability, or asset: 'he was endowed with tremendous physical strength'", even on the Google results themselves. Voting to close and downvoting.

"Richly endowed" means having a lot of something. Literally, it means money, as you suppose. It is also often used non-literally to mean having a lot of something else. You could say, "He was richly endowed with many useful skills." It's common to say that a woman is "well-endowed" to mean that she has a large bust.
Here, it means he had all those things just listed: good looking and fierce in battle.
What does "the joy of a man richly endowed" look like? It means he had a look of someone who was happy with himself and content. I don't know how to describe a facial expression and posture beyond that.

I haven't seen well endowed used on women

@Tim I was going mention that it can often have the connotation of risqué commentary on someone's sexualized physical attributes, and is used of men too. That's not intended by this passage, but was the first thing I thought of when I read the title.

The original text uses dapsilis, which dictionaries translate as richly provided with everything - presumably in terms of material wealth, physical attributes, and whatever else one may have. "Lacked for nothing" might be a good modern English analogue - endowed is fine, technically, but nowadays it has a connotation with a rather specific part of male physique.

@AndyBonner Yes, also used of men. I didn't intend to say EXCLUSIVELY used to describe women, that was just an example.

@Tim https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/well-endowed, for example
